# React Scheduler customize Appointment Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress, react-props

I am using [React Scheduler](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/scheduler/docs/guides/getting-started/) and I am trying to customize the [AppointmentForm](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/scheduler/docs/reference/appointment-form/). I want to set a default value to the title field in the form creation and disable few of the fields. [This issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues/3187) explains how to delete all the fields of the form, but I couldn't understand how to choose which ones I want to keep as default and which to change and how. I would highly appreciate an example of this.

My current code has all the default props and a custom one, and I wish to be able to change the default props:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { ViewState, EditingState } from '@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler';
import {Scheduler, Appointments, AppointmentForm, AppointmentTooltip,WeekView,Toolbar,
DateNavigator,EditRecurrenceMenu,ConfirmationDialog
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler-material-ui';
import { Alert } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';



const theme = createTheme();
  
const DataSheet = () => {
  ...
  const TextEditor = (props) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/destructuring-assignment
    if (props.type === 'multilineTextEditor') {
      return null;
    } return <AppointmentForm.TextEditor {...props} />;
  };

  const BasicLayout = ({ onFieldChange, appointmentData, ...restProps }) => {
    return (
      <AppointmentForm.BasicLayout
        appointmentData={appointmentData}
        onFieldChange={onFieldChange}
        {...restProps}   
      >
        <AppointmentForm.TextEditor
          value = {userFullName}
          type="title"
        />
      </AppointmentForm.BasicLayout>
    );
  };

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="lg">
          <CssBaseline />
          <Box
            sx= ...
            >
            <Scheduler
              data={shifts}
              height= "auto"
            >
              <ViewState
                defaultCurrentDate={defaultCurrentDate}
                defaultCurrentViewName="Week"
              />
              <EditingState
                onCommitChanges={commitChanges}
              />
              <WeekView
                cellDuration={60}
                startDayHour={9}
                endDayHour={22}
              />
              <EditRecurrenceMenu />
              <Toolbar />
              <DateNavigator />
              <Appointments />
              <AppointmentTooltip
                showOpenButton
                showDeleteButton
              />
              <AppointmentForm
              basicLayoutComponent={BasicLayout}
              textEditorComponent={TextEditor}
              />
            </Scheduler>
            </Box>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default DataSheet
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends in on what do you want to edit/delete, here is my example:

```
  const BoolEditor = (props) => {
    return null;
  };
  const LabelComponent = (props) => {
    if (props.text === 'Details') {
      return <AppointmentForm.Label
      { ...props} 
      text="Precio Modulo"
      />  
    } else if (props.text === 'More Information') {
      return null
    } else if (props.text === '-') {
      return <AppointmentForm.Label
      { ...props}
      />  
    }
  };
  const InputComponent = (props) => {
    if (props.type === 'titleTextEditor') {
      return <AppointmentForm.TextEditor
      { ...props}
      type='numberEditor'
      placeholder='Precio'
      />
    }
  };

  // cambio el layout
  const BasicLayout = ({ onFieldChange, appointmentData, ...restProps }) => {
    return (
      <AppointmentForm.BasicLayout
        appointmentData={appointmentData}
        onFieldChange={onFieldChange}
        {...restProps}   
      >
      </AppointmentForm.BasicLayout>
    );
  };

  // retorno el calendario 
  return (
    <>
    <h1 style={{ 'textAlign': 'center' }}>Horario del Profesor:</h1>
        <Paper>
        <Scheduler
          data={schedulerData}
        >

          <ViewState
            defaultCurrentDate={currentDate}
            defaultCurrentViewName="Week"
          />

          <EditingState
            onCommitChanges={commitChanges}
          />
          <IntegratedEditing />

          <DayView
            startDayHour={7}
            endDayHour={23}
          />
          <WeekView startDayHour={7} endDayHour={23} />

          <Toolbar />
          <DateNavigator />
          <TodayButton />
          <ViewSwitcher />
          <ConfirmationDialog />
          <Appointments />
          <AppointmentTooltip
            showCloseButton
            showOpenButton
          />
          <AppointmentForm
            readOnly={isNormalUser}
            basicLayoutComponent={BasicLayout}
            booleanEditorComponent={BoolEditor}
            labelComponent={LabelComponent}
            textEditorComponent={InputComponent}
          />
        </Scheduler>
      </Paper>
      <br />
      <br />
      </>
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, couldn't get your code to work but it helped me nonetheless